# what is fuzzy svm?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, fuzzy-logic

I have to solve this question for my homework but I don't get how to formulate svm to FSVM. can someone please guide me?

> What is your idea to have a model of SVM classifier in which instances can belong to both classes
>       with associated membership values? Model it in both primal and dual problem. Model an
>       unsupervised version of SVM and solve it!